# trying to consume a WCF service in silverlight application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, wcf

I created a silver light project,where i am trying to load a datagrid in my main page.As I came to know that ADO.net is not supported in silverlight ,i made use of silver light enabled WCF service.I followed the example here http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=228

I am able to get the data from the database into the service but unable to display in my page and it doesn't throw any exception.Does it have some thing to do with the binding configurations or some thing.Because i am able to access the WCF service from the browser .so i think i am unable to load into the datagrid of my page.Here is my code

XAML:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="DetailsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="430" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="576" />
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
    DataServiceClient client = new DataServiceClient();
  client.ResourcesListCompleted  +=new EventHandler<ResourcesListCompletedEventArgs>(client_ResourcesListCompleted);
        client.ResourcesListAsync();
        InitializeComponent();

    void client_ResourcesListCompleted(object sender, ResourcesListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        DetailsGrid.ItemSource = e.Result;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` but then (assuming you haven't left it out of the code) not specified which columns you do want to display.

In the first instance set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` to make sure you are getting data. This will display all the data for each record in the data set. If you don't want all the data set it to `False` and then specify which columns you do want to use. So assuming you have a field called `FirstName` in your data you'd have:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" 
                Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    ....
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Comment: :Its working perfectly fine now when i set the AutogenerateColums="True";